# Increase the height of UIToolbar that comes with UINavigationController

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

Not able to increase the height of UIToolbar that comes with UINavigationController by using following lines inside viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear() in Swift3

```
self.navigationController?.toolbar.frame.size.height += 10
self.navigationController?.toolbar.frame.origin.y -= 10
```

Also tried with Interface Builder but the height property is disabled there:-

[image]

Please suggest what to do